Solving $\frac1{x^4}+\frac1{(x+1)^4}=2$
I need a help with an algebraic equation of degree $4$.

$$\frac{1}{x^4}+\frac{1}{(x+1)^4}=2$$

I have tried to solve the equation by change of variable and trying to find differences of squares but I can't find a solution. I would like to know what advice you can give me or if there is an appropriate change of variable that will help me solve it.

Did you try the substitution $t=x+\frac12$?

Putting this into WA gives two real solutions which look like the solutions to a messy cubic. So I think the best you'll be able to do is reduce it to a cubic, which suggests that the problem is not really "precalculus".

@MathGuy Yes, I already used it but I find solutions that are not, in itself, I must come to the solution that it is 0.850115

The substitution suggested by Math Guy brings the equation to a form such that the eight (complex) solutions are square roots of the zeros of a quartic. Looks like the Galois group of that quartic is full $S_4$, so no shortcuts to using the quartic formula.

From the suggestion of @MathGuy, the equation is equivalent to
$$ -2x^8 + 2x^6 + \frac{5}{4} x^4 + \frac{25}{8} x^2 + \frac{15}{128} = 0$$ If we denote $y = x^2$, you obtain then a quartic equation and can solve it with closed form solution.

Maple gives 8 solutions, based on the quartic equation as suggested by @NN2.
The only real one is the first and the second one:
$$
x=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{9+6 \sqrt{3}\, \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}+6 \sqrt{3}\, \sqrt{\frac{-\sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}\, \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+12 \sqrt{3}\, \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+4 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}+5 \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}}}}}{6}
\approx 0.85
$$
$$
x-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{9+6 \sqrt{3}\, \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}+6 \sqrt{3}\, \sqrt{\frac{-\sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}\, \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+12 \sqrt{3}\, \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+4 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}+5 \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}}}}}{6}
\approx -1.85
$$
$$
-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\mathrm{I} \sqrt{-9-6 \sqrt{3}\, \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}+6 \sqrt{3}\, \sqrt{\frac{-\sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}\, \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+12 \sqrt{3}\, \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+4 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}+5 \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}}}}}{6}
$$
$$
-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\mathrm{I} \sqrt{-9-6 \sqrt{3}\, \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}+6 \sqrt{3}\, \sqrt{\frac{-\sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}\, \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+12 \sqrt{3}\, \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+4 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}+5 \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}}}}}{6}
$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{9+6 \,\mathrm{I} \sqrt{3}\, \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}\, \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+12 \sqrt{3}\, \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-4 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}-5 \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}}}-6 \sqrt{3}\, \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}}}{6}
$$
$$
-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{9+6 \,\mathrm{I} \sqrt{3}\, \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}\, \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+12 \sqrt{3}\, \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-4 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}-5 \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}}}-6 \sqrt{3}\, \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}}}{6}
$$
$$
-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{9-6 \,\mathrm{I} \sqrt{3}\, \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}\, \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+12 \sqrt{3}\, \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-4 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}-5 \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}}}-6 \sqrt{3}\, \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}}}{6}
$$
$$
-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{9-6 \,\mathrm{I} \sqrt{3}\, \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}\, \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+12 \sqrt{3}\, \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-4 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}-5 \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}}}-6 \sqrt{3}\, \sqrt{\frac{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2 \left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-5}{\left(35+15 \sqrt{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}}}{6}
$$

Sorry, there're are of course two real root, which sum up to $-1$.
